# Drop down menu not working when I add picture?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, navigationbar

This is a theme for a tumblr. This part of the code is for the drop down menu. I'm pretty new to all this and am very confused. When I added the 5th image the drop down menu stops working. If I add a 6th image it breaks the navigation completely. I'm a total amateur and this is only part of the code... any help is appreciated.

```
<!-- NAVIGATION SECOND LEVEL -->
<ul class="nav-sl image-dd-menu">
    <li class="image-dd-cat image-cat-1">
        {block:IfImageDropdownCategory1URL}
        <a class="link-validate image-dd-pic" href="{text:Image dropdown category 1 url}">
            <a href="{block:ImageDropdownCategory1PictureLink}"></a><img src="{image:Image dropdown category 1 picture}">{/block:ImageDropdownCategory1PictureLink}</a>
            {block:IfImageDropdownCategory1Name}
                <div>{text:Image dropdown category 1 name}</div>
            {/block:IfImageDropdownCategory1Name}
        {/block:IfImageDropdownCategory1URL}
        {block:IfNotImageDropdownCategory1URL}
        <div class="image-dd-pic">
            <img src="{image:Image dropdown category 1 picture}">
            {block:IfImageDropdownCategory1Name}
                <div>{text:Image dropdown category 1 name}</div>
            {/block:IfImageDropdownCategory1Name}
        </div>
        {/block:IfNotImageDropdownCategory1URL}
        <div class="image-dd-links">
            {block:IfImageDropdownCat1Link1Url}
            <a class="link-validate" href="{text:Image dropdown cat 1 link 1 url}">{text:Image dropdown cat 1 link 1 text}</a>
            {/block:IfImageDropdownCat1Link1Url}
            {block:IfImageDropdownCat1Link2Url}
            <a class="link-validate" href="{text:Image dropdown cat 1 link 2 url}">{text:Image dropdown cat 1 link 2 text}</a>
            {/block:IfImageDropdownCat1Link2Url}
            {block:IfImageDropdownCat1Link3Url}
            <a class="link-validate" href="{text:Image dropdown cat 1 link 3 url}">{text:Image dropdown cat 1 link 3 text}</a>
            {/block:IfImageDropdownCat1Link3Url}
            {block:IfImageDropdownCat1Link4Url}
            <a class="link-validate" href="{text:Image dropdown cat 1 link 4 url}">{text:Image dropdown cat 1 link 4 text}</a>
            {/block:IfImageDropdownCat1Link4Url}
            {block:IfImageDropdownCat1Link5Url}
            <a class="link-validate" href="{text:Image dropdown cat 1 link 5 url}">{text:Image dropdown cat 1 link 5 text}</a>
            {/block:IfImageDropdownCat1Link5Url}
        </div>    
    </li>
    <li class="image-dd-cat image-cat-2">
        {block:IfImageDropdownCategory2URL}
        <a class="link-validate image-dd-pic" href="{text:Image dropdown category 2 url}">
            <img src="{image:Image dropdown category 2 picture}">
            {block:IfImageDropdownCategory2Name}
                <div>{text:Image dropdown category 2 name}</div>
            {/block:IfImageDropdownCategory2Name}
        </a>
        {/block:IfImageDropdownCategory2URL}
        {block:IfNotImageDropdownCategory2URL}
        <div class="image-dd-pic">
            <img src="{image:Image dropdown category 2 picture}">
            {block:IfImageDropdownCategory2Name}
                <div>{text:Image dropdown category 2 name}</div>
            {/block:IfImageDropdownCategory2Name}    
        </div>
        {/block:IfNotImageDropdownCategory2URL}
        <div class="image-dd-links">
            {block:IfImageDropdownCat2Link1Url}
            <a class="link-validate" href="{text:Image dropdown cat 2 link 1 url}">{text:Image dropdown cat 2 link 1 text}</a>
            {/block:IfImageDropdownCat2Link1Url}
            {block:IfImageDropdownCat2Link2Url}
            <a class="link-validate" href="{text:Image dropdown cat 2 link 2 url}">{text:Image dropdown cat 2 link 2 text}</a>
            {/block:IfImageDropdownCat2Link2Url}
            {block:IfImageDropdownCat2Link3Url}
            <a class="link-validate" href="{text:Image dropdown cat 2 link 3 url}">{text:Image dropdown cat 2 link 3 text}</a>
            {/block:IfImageDropdownCat2Link3Url}
            {block:IfImageDropdownCat2Link4Url}
            <a class="link-validate" href="{text:Image dropdown cat 2 link 4 url}">{text:Image dropdown cat 2 link 4 text}</a>
            {/block:IfImageDropdownCat2Link4Url}
            {block:IfImageDropdownCat2Link5Url}
            <a class="link-validate" href="{text:Image dropdown cat 2 link 5 url}">{text:Image dropdown cat 2 link 5 text}</a>
            {/block:IfImageDropdownCat2Link5Url}
        </div>    
    </li>
    <li class="image-dd-cat image-cat-3">
        {block:IfImageDropdownCategory3URL}
        <a class="link-validate image-dd-pic" href="{text:Image dropdown category 3 url}">
            <img src="{image:Image dropdown category 3 picture}">
            {block:IfImageDropdownCategory3Name}
                <div>{text:Image dropdown category 3 name}</div>
            {/block:IfImageDropdownCategory3Name}    
        </a>
        {/block:IfImageDropdownCategory3URL}
        {block:IfNotImageDropdownCategory3URL}
        <div class="image-dd-pic">
            <img src="{image:Image dropdown category 3 picture}">
            {block:IfImageDropdownCategory3Name}
                <div>{text:Image dropdown category 3 name}</div>
            {/block:IfImageDropdownCategory3Name}    
        </div>
        {/block:IfNotImageDropdownCategory3URL}
        <div class="image-dd-links">
            {block:IfImageDropdownCat3Link1Url}
            <a class="link-validate" href="{text:Image dropdown cat 3 link 1 url}">{text:Image dropdown cat 3 link 1 text}</a>
            {/block:IfImageDropdownCat3Link1Url}
            {block:IfImageDropdownCat3Link2Url}
            <a class="link-validate" href="{text:Image dropdown cat 3 link 2 url}">{text:Image dropdown cat 3 link 2 text}</a>
            {/block:IfImageDropdownCat3Link2Url}
            {block:IfImageDropdownCat3Link3Url}
            <a class="link-validate" href="{text:Image dropdown cat 3 link 3 url}">{text:Image dropdown cat 3 link 3 text}</a>
            {/block:IfImageDropdownCat3Link3Url}
            {block:IfImageDropdownCat3Link4Url}
            <a class="link-validate" href="{text:Image dropdown cat 3 link 4 url}">{text:Image dropdown cat 3 link 4 text}</a>
            {/block:IfImageDropdownCat3Link4Url}
            {block:IfImageDropdownCat3Link5Url}
            <a class="link-validate" href="{text:Image dropdown cat 3 link 5 url}">{text:Image dropdown cat 3 link 5 text}</a>
            {/block:IfImageDropdownCat3Link5Url}
        </div>    
    </li>
    <li class="image-dd-cat image-cat-4">
        {block:IfImageDropdownCategory4URL}
        <a class="link-validate image-dd-pic" href="{text:Image dropdown category 4 url}">
            <img src="{image:Image dropdown category 4 picture}">
            {block:IfImageDropdownCategory4Name}
                <div>{text:Image dropdown category 4 name}</div>
            {/block:IfImageDropdownCategory4Name}    
        </a>
        {/block:IfImageDropdownCategory4URL}
        {block:IfNotImageDropdownCategory4URL}
        <div class="image-dd-pic">
            <img src="{image:Image dropdown category 4 picture}">
            {block:IfImageDropdownCategory4Name}
                <div>{text:Image dropdown category 4 name}</div>
            {/block:IfImageDropdownCategory4Name}    
        </div>
        {/block:IfNotImageDropdownCategory4URL}
        <div class="image-dd-links">
            {block:IfImageDropdownCat4Link1Url}
            <a class="link-validate" href="{text:Image dropdown cat 4 link 1 url}">{text:Image dropdown cat 4 link 1 text}</a>
            {/block:IfImageDropdownCat4Link1Url}
            {block:IfImageDropdownCat4Link2Url}
            <a class="link-validate" href="{text:Image dropdown cat 4 link 2 url}">{text:Image dropdown cat 4 link 2 text}</a>
            {/block:IfImageDropdownCat4Link2Url}
            {block:IfImageDropdownCat4Link3Url}
            <a class="link-validate" href="{text:Image dropdown cat 4 link 3 url}">{text:Image dropdown cat 4 link 3 text}</a>
            {/block:IfImageDropdownCat4Link3Url}
            {block:IfImageDropdownCat4Link4Url}
            <a class="link-validate" href="{text:Image dropdown cat 4 link 4 url}">{text:Image dropdown cat 4 link 4 text}</a>
            {/block:IfImageDropdownCat4Link4Url}
            {block:IfImageDropdownCat4Link5Url}
            <a class="link-validate" href="{text:Image dropdown cat 4 link 5 url}">{text:Image dropdown cat 4 link 5 text}</a>
            {/block:IfImageDropdownCat4Link5Url}

        </div>    
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav-sl image-dd-menu">
    <li class="image-dd-cat image-cat-5">
        {block:IfImageDropdownCategory5URL}
        <a class="link-validate image-dd-pic" href="{text:Image dropdown category 5 url}">
            <img src="{image:Image dropdown category 5 picture}">
            {block:IfImageDropdownCategory5Name}
                <div>{text:Image dropdown category 5 name}</div>
            {/block:IfImageDropdownCategory5Name}    
        </a>
        {/block:IfImageDropdownCategory5URL}
        {block:IfNotImageDropdownCategory5URL}
        <div class="image-dd-pic">
            <img src="{image:Image dropdown category 5 picture}">
            {block:IfImageDropdownCategory5Name}
                <div>{text:Image dropdown category 5 name}</div>
            {/block:IfImageDropdownCategory5Name}    
        </div>
        {/block:IfNotImageDropdownCategory5URL}
        <div class="image-dd-links">
            {block:IfImageDropdownCat5Link1Url}
            <a class="link-validate" href="{text:Image dropdown cat 5 link 1 url}">{text:Image dropdown cat 3 link 1 text}</a>
            {/block:IfImageDropdownCat5Link1Url}
            {block:IfImageDropdownCat5Link2Url}
            <a class="link-validate" href="{text:Image dropdown cat 5 link 2 url}">{text:Image dropdown cat 5 link 2 text}</a>
            {/block:IfImageDropdownCat5Link2Url}
            {block:IfImageDropdownCat5Link3Url}
            <a class="link-validate" href="{text:Image dropdown cat 5 link 3 url}">{text:Image dropdown cat 5 link 3 text}</a>
            {/block:IfImageDropdownCat5Link3Url}
            {block:IfImageDropdownCat5Link4Url}
            <a class="link-validate" href="{text:Image dropdown cat 5 link 4 url}">{text:Image dropdown cat 5 link 4 text}</a>
            {/block:IfImageDropdownCat5Link4Url}
            {block:IfImageDropdownCat5Link5Url}
            <a class="link-validate" href="{text:Image dropdown cat 5 link 5 url}">{text:Image dropdown cat 5 link 5 text}</a>
            {/block:IfImageDropdownCat5Link5Url}
        </div>    
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Can you make a http://jsfiddle.net or code snippet demo of your code? The code you have given us is not completely html/javascript. And please post the relevant javascript. So we can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: would it just be better if I posted the whole code? its kinda massive

Comment: Yes, but post only the code what is relevant. It would be better if you could make it minimal to reproduce your issue.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/sMS63YUM will this work?